# Are there any expanded universe works that feature intelligent starships?

Tags: star-trek

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/why-dont-starfleet-vessels-have-intelligent-on-board-computers) covers why Starfleet isn't terribly keen on intelligent starships ([M-5](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/M-5_multitronic_unit) being a prominent example), and why there hasn't been much in the way of advances in the field, in-canon.

However, I'm curious about the expanded universe.  Do any expanded universe works feature the development of intelligent starships, or starships that develop their own intelligence?  In particular, do any of them feature a Starfleet starship with advanced AI capable of independent action and thought? Especially, ships developed past the end of TV and Movie canon, or that develop their intelligence past that point in time.

Comment: Are you ignoring the M-5 Computer test seen in TOS: "The Ultimate Computer"?

Comment: @Richard See: Starfleet isn't terribly keen on intelligent starships. M-5 perhaps being the most prominent example of all.  **However**, I should clarify that if the M-5 makes an appearance in an expanded univrerse work, I would probably count it, though I'm really looking for *future* starships.

Comment: Starships aren't TARDIS. Unlike TARDIS, Starships are built, not grown.

Comment: @zibbobz - I can't think of any. The only other example I can think of of a computer being given **deliberate control** is the ECH

Comment: @Richard Which I do recall, but wouldn't consider valid here - I'm thinking of a situation like the one where Enterprise D took control of itself in order to give birth to a baby (yes, that happened)

Comment: @Zibbobz - I'm confused. Are you referring to situations where intelligences have *emerged* or where an AI is *deliberately installed*

Comment: @Richard Both, really.

Comment: It seems like the next gen Enterprise was partly intelligent, after all it was used as the basis for an emergent intelligence in one episode (but I guess you only care about EU works).   Star Trek AIs aren't specifically tied to ships, though, as often as they are in other newer space operas/odysseys.

Comment: One sorta example I can think of would be the [USS Galen](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Galen_%28NX-86350%29).  While it isn't run by the computer directly, most of the crew is holographic, including The Doctor.

Comment: @Compro01, if you are going to consider control by a hologram, you could possibly include Voyager.  The doctor was left in command a couple times.

Comment: @SachinShekhar, it seems likely that the Bio-neural gel packs had to be grown.

Comment: @Compro01 If you're gonna go there, no need to go non-canon.  VOY 7x09, [Flesh and Blood](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flesh_and_Blood_(episode)), had a ship run entirely by sentient holograms (that later founded a colony).  Zibbobz, are these acceptable answers?

Comment: Oof...those are tough ones.  The Gel Packs I don't think I'd count, but the holo-crew is right on the verge, because technically they ARE all an extension of the ship...but I'll have to say no, because they're all separate entities on the ship.  None of them would identify themselves as that specific ship, they're still crew members, they just happen to be holo-generated crew members.

Comment: @Izkata - Yes, but the question specified "expanded universe" rather than show canon.

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes one recent example is SecondGen White-Blue a [Sentry](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry) . Their species of living technology is encountered in the Titan's expedition into the beta quadrant. When Titan encounters the Sentry's civilization it is revealed that every modern Starfleet ship could become sentient. Titan does become alive as well.

There is also the living civilization/ships/galaxies of [The Body Electric](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Body_Electric) an organism so powerful it scares [the Travelers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Traveler) but not ever brave Mr. Crusher. In the book titled the Body Electric there are AI's of various types one of which is a ship.